# Long URLs works with Python requests but not CURL or web browsers (nginx-uwsgi-django)

Tags: nginx, url, get, uwsgi

I want to enable relatively long URLs to work on my site.

In Python, it works pretty well:

```py
import requests


base_url = 'https://myurl.com'
client = requests.session()
gs = ['FAM20558-i1-1.1']


for i in [100,1000,1100]:
    r = client.get(url=f'{base_url}/api/validate-genomes', params={'genomes[]': gs * i})
    print(i, r.text)
```

Output:

```
100 {"success": true}
1000 {"success": true}
1100 <html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.14.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

So it works fine until `i=1000`, which is all I need.

For `i=300`, [the URL](https://myurl.com/api/validate-genomes/?genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1) is 9071 characters long. Size according to sys.getsizeof: 9120 bytes. It looks like this: `https://myurl.com/api/validate-genomes/?genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&genomes%5B%5D=FAM20558-i1-1.1&...`

But when I try to CURL the URL or copy this URL into the browser, it will not work! Nor do ajax requests with this length work. Why is that? How can I fix it? (Requests with `i=100` always work.)

CURL output (`curl --http2 -v $URL`):

```
> Host: myurl.com
> user-agent: curl/7.71.1
> accept: */*
> 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS alert, close notify (256):
* Empty reply from server
* Closing connection 0
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, close notify (256):
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

In nginx access.log, I see:

```
<MY IP> - - [04/Feb/2021:11:06:58 +0100] "-" 000 0 "-" "-" "-"
```

No change in nginx error.log.

The relevant nginx config (not sure it matters):

```
upstream django {
    server unix:///path/to/socket.sock;
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;

    client_max_body_size        10M;

    uwsgi_buffer_size           128k;
    uwsgi_buffers               12 128k;
    uwsgi_busy_buffers_size     256k;

    client_header_buffer_size   5120k;
    large_client_header_buffers 16 5120k;

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass django;
        include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

#EDIT: I understand that in this case, POST requests make more sense. But I want long URLs elsewhere, and this is a convenient way to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I specified `--http1.1` in the CURL request, it worked! The problem was with http2. Found the solution here: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T209590

I had to increase the `http2_max_field_size` and `http2_max_header_size` in my nginx config.